# CMake activate external program

Tags: cmake, external-process

I want to run the following command

```
win_bison.exe --output="calc.tab.cpp" --defines="calc.tab.h"  "calc.y"
```

and then create an executable from the products of this command with CMake

```
add_executable(Calc calc.tab.cpp calc.tab.h)
```

All the files (win_bison.exe, calc.y) are found in the `CMakeLists.txt` folder.

What is the correct way to do so? Please give the commands explanations.

Answer (score 0):

If your project is indeed structured like that, then you can use the [`FindBison`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindBISON.html) CMake module

```
find_package(BISON)

BISON_TARGET(MyCalcParser calc.y 
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/calc.tab.cpp
  DEFINES_FILE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/calc.tab.h)

add_executable(Calc ${BISON_MyCalcParser_OUTPUTS})
```

Notes

- You might have to influence the places the `find_package` searches by setting the `BISON_DIR` variable in the command line invocation of CMake, i.e. `-DBISON_DIR=[source dir]`, or you can place the Bison executable somwhere that is system-wide accessible/invocable.